# 2011 Volkswagen Routan Transmission issues

Tags: vw, transmission, automatic-transmission

2011 Volkswagen Routan SE Van (daily driver) gave a transmission code 
P0841: transmission fluid pressure sensor switch A.

We had a friend change the engine oil and the ATF. They also changed the transmission filter which requires removing the pan. They added 5/6 qts of engine oil to the crankcase, and x/5.5 qts to the ATF. I hope they replaced what was taken out but there are some bigger questions. We cleared the codes and continued driving. We then did a Seafoam Top Cleaner through a Vacuum hose of the intake, bypassing the throttle body. This produced a very smoky exhaust, which we expected. But the transmission started having trouble changing gears, accelerating over 40mph. Checked the codes again and now we have transmissions ABC

P0841: Transmission fluid pressure sensor switch circuit A

P0846: Transmission fluid pressure sensor switch circuit B

P0871: Transmission fluid pressure sensor switch circuit C

All this happened over the course of 2-3 weeks.
When I searched for parts for a pressure sensor switch A, the results did not look like an electric sensor.
My questions, if I can fix the A circuit will that save our transmission? How do I purchase the proper 2011 VW OEM circuit?
Could the sensor be dirty, would a transmission cleaner like Seafoam Hydra Trans Tune + flush have the desired sensor cleaning capabilities?!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnfpD.jpg)[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Have you checked for broken, loose or chafed wires ?

Comment: The transmission can go into a "limp" mode where it won't change out of second gear if some error codes happen.  So, just because it won't shift doesn't mean that it can't shift or is broken.  It could be a simple fix like a loose wire as Mike suggests.  Also, keep in mind that this is just a Dodge Caravan, so keep that in your searches as well if looking for Routan specific help doesn't work.

Comment: No broken wires, there are signs of leaking oil, it was changed a month ago, I can’t believe it would be from the last change. I will look into the Dodge Caravan.

Comment: You say "They only added 5 qts of engine oil" I sure hope they did not put back engine oil in your transmission. If this is a typo please fix, if not that is probably your problem

Comment: We ended up trading it in, and avoided paying the trans-medic to change the original code circuit. So we will never know if it was savable.